# Windows XP joining Windows 7 HomeGroup

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, homegroup

How can my Windows XP computer join my Windows 7 laptop's HomeGroup?

Comment: See this help article...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Microsoft article :
[Windows 7 & HomeGroup: Sharing with Windows XP, Windows Vista, and other operating systems](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=80B1AA5D-1B5A-4447-8036-ACC918BA7AF2).

In short, only Win7 computers can *fully* join in the HomeGroup, but the network is still usable from XP in the classical way, through "My Network Places" -> "View workgroup computers", double-click the computer you want to access and enter the credentials when asked.

You should first ensure that the [Link Layer Topology Discovery](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f01a31d-ee46-481e-ba11-37f485fa34ea&displaylang=en) (LLTD) is installed on the XP computer, as described [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5306930_install-protocol-windows-xp-sp.html).

Comment: Well, I made that from Windows XP I can see Windows 7 but from Windows 7 I can't see Windows XP, any solutions?

Comment: In the above paper, see the chapter "Sharing with Windows 7 from Windows XP or Windows Vista" page 25.

Comment: It was router problem, but now I want ask about printer, if it's connected to Windows XP, why I need that printer's driver on my Windows 7? (asking because I couldn't finder drivers for Windows 7)

Comment: The printer driver is used to generate the print job on the originating machine, so you need it on both sides. The simplest way is to connect the printer directly to 7 temporarily by cable/usb and let it install the driver.

Comment: It doesn't work, and I couldn't find drivers for Windows 7 for HP Laserjet 1000 on their site

Comment: I believe your driver is [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/genericSoftwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&softwareitem=bi-65215-1&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN).

Comment: I get: ...is not valid Win32 application

Comment: Download again.

Comment: Downloaded and still get same error

Answer (score 0):

It can't.  Homegroups are only supported in Windows 7.  They can, however share files and printers using good old networking.

Comment: Could you tell me more about good old networking? or is it same as harrymc answered?

Comment: By "good old networking" I just meant the form of networking that was around before Win7 homegroups.  It's the same as Harry's answer.